# how to copy text from a mac terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal, linux-terminal

I am new to mac. I am trying to copy text from a mac terminal. I tried the usual way of trying to drag the cursor over the text, this is  working consistently when I select text from a texteditor or browser. However, in case of the mac terminal, it sometimes work but sometimes it just gives a yellow pop up and disappears. What am i missing here?
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That is what I am asking here, I am not able to make the selection sometimes, when I try to make a selection, a yellow popup comes sometimes.

Comment: https://scriptingosx.com/2017/03/terminal-and-the-clipboard/
Use ⌘C ⌘V

Comment: You seem to have some sort of 'graphic' selector there, not a text selector. Honestly, I've no idea how you managed to do that. Terminal should always just behave as 'text'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a laptop, then you may have it set to force click - a sort of harder click -- resulting in looking up a word. Go to settings, search for force click, disable it, and you won't have this problem again.

[Force Click](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).