# how to copy text from a mac terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal

I am new to mac. I am trying to copy text from a mac terminal. I tried the usual way of trying to drag the cursor over the text, this is working consistently when I select text from a texteditor or browser. However, in case of the mac terminal, it sometimes work but sometimes it just gives a yellow pop up and disappears. What am i missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ask on the Apple SE site or super user

Comment: This migration should be rejected. Question was already cross-posted to Server Fault & Super User. https://superuser.com/questions/1694519/how-to-copy-text-from-a-mac-terminal